# <!-- Render Failed--> bug

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, web-part, document-library

I have a big document list and show this on my website. But sometimes i get this error ,"Render Failed".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reasons for this error:

1. The document library has exceeded the 5k list view threshold.
2. According to other posts which has similar issue, it is possibly related to custom solutions or special columns in the list.

   References:
   [Listviewwebpart doesn't render the data and shows “RENDER FAILED”.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86667/listviewwebpart-doesnt-render-the-data-and-shows-render-failed) /
   [Getting  error while rendering sharepoint list view.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c3652f45-2c73-4b98-99ab-7b3d8a86d797/getting-render-failed-error-while-rendering-sharepoint-list-view?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)
3. You use grouping/filtering/totals features in the current list view:
   [#RENDER FAILED IN VIEW WITH TOTALS AND GROUPING.](https://blog.davidjwise.com/2007/11/05/renderfailedtotalsgroup/)

A few things you can try:

1. Modify this view and remove lookup columns/person or group columns if any.
2. Remove list view filters if any. Change the GROUP BY options between *Collapsed* and *Expanded*.
3. If none of these actions can solve this issue, consider splitting the document library into multiple libraries and keep the number of documents under the limit.